# loop of a 100 animations with specific delay

Tags: javascript, css, for-loop

I'm trying to make 100 animations that each of them has a different delay.
Something is wrong because each  doesn't receive his specific animation.
Here's the code:

```
var text = $("#cont").text();
var count = 1;
var before = 0;
var after = 0;
var counter = "";
for (var i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
    for (var j = 1; j <= 5; j++) {
        counter = before + "." + after;
        after += 2;
        text += "<div class='ball' id='ball" + count + "'></div><br />";
        $("#ball" + count).css({
            "-webkit-animation": "ball 3.5s linear" + counter + "s infinite normal",
            "-moz-animation": "ball 3.5s linear" + counter + "s infinite normal",
            "-ms-animation": "ball 3.5s linear" + counter + "s infinite normal",
            "-o-animation": "ball 3.5s linear" + counter + "s infinite normal",
            "animation": "ball 3.5s linear" + counter + "s infinite normal",
        });
        count++;
    }
    after = 0;
    before++;
}
i--;
$("#cont").html(text);
```

Comment: Add your HTML and CSS. And also create a Fiddle?

Comment: @Sourabh http://jsfiddle.net/FMBNc/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to apply `.css()` to a string of `text`, which is your problem area as `css()` only works on DOM objects.The other thing is you were putting `text` in the DOM after your loop is completed, so any of your css had already been completed in the loop. I changed it so you're appending the html to the `$('#cont')` object in the loop so it can be manipulated.

You can see the fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/FMBNc/3/

Also created an alternate where you're only applying the animation-delay and declaring the rest of the animation in the CSS document: http://jsfiddle.net/FMBNc/4/

```
var text = $("#cont"); //changed to just the object
var count = 1;
var before = 0;
var after = 0;
var counter = "";
for (var i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
    for (var j = 1; j <= 5; j++) {
        counter = before + "." + after;
        after += 2;
        //putting the html object in the DOM so it can be manipulated by .css()
        text.append("<div class='ball' id='ball" + count + "'></div>");
        $("#ball" + count).css({
            "-webkit-animation": "ball 3.5s linear " + counter + "s infinite",
            "-moz-animation": "ball 3.5s linear " + counter + "s infinite",
            "-ms-animation": "ball 3.5s linear " + counter + "s infinite",
            "-o-animation": "ball 3.5s linear " + counter + "s infinite",
            "animation": "ball 3.5s linear " + counter + "s infinite"
        });
        count++;
    }
    after = 0;
    before++;
}
```

Also, you don't need `normal` in your CSS declaration as it's a default.

Comment: THANK YOU!
BTW, I like your remake (the 2nd link).